# SPSS GEE: which type of model to select?

Tags: spss, generalized-estimating-equations

I would like to conduct a GEE analysis (repeated measures logistic regression) but I am not sure whether my data allows me to run a GEE Binary Logistic Model or if I should use GEE Binomial Identity Model (custom).

My participants took a pre-test then learned words and were tested on the same words again.
My dependent variable = score on posttest/word (0 or 1)  (words already known on pre-test are left empty)
My subject variable = participant
My within-subject variable = words
Predictors: two categoricals and one scale (that characterized words) + 1 scale (that characterized participants).
Here is what my data looks like:
[image]

I want to know whether words that have the value 1 for the predictors are more likely to be learned than words that have value 0...
Can someone help please? Is it allowed to use a Binary Logistic in this case?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi, what is a “binomial identity model”?

Comment: Binomial is used when the Y variable is dichotomous (0 or 1) and the identity link is sometimes used for binomial data to yield a linear probability model.

Comment: @FievezIsabeau Not exactly. Binomial does not actually require the Y is dichotomous - it can model proportions. There are other models (cloglog, poisson) to consider in case Y is dichotomous. Specifying binomial in this case creates a mean-variance structure such that the variance is p * (1-p) where p is the mean.

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference in the data to which these two models can be applied. Both are designed for binary response data. Technically, a linear probability model can't be correct with binary data, since it generally predicts probabilities outside of the 0-1 range of the response, but as a practical matter the results from the two are often pretty similar.